# Generating Numbers

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Applying the steps below, you will generate a number, on the condition that every digit of a number produced in each step is different from its other digits.

> 1. Write down a number with one, two or three digits.
> 2. Delete at most three consecutive digits and in the places of the deleted digits place the square of the number formed by these digits.
> 3. For the number you get, repeat steps two and three. If you cannot get a number that satisfies the conditions, stop.

What is the largest number that can be generated through this mechanism?

**Example:** 307, 3(07), 349, 3(4)9, 3169, ...

**Source:** Puzzleup 2010

Comment: Could the tag "computer-puzzle" be appropriate or is this really doable with logical deduction?

Comment: @A.P. well, you are free to find it by a computer, I am not sure whether if it is needed. not my original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this didn't had a no-computers tag. I used a computer program.

The answer is as follows:

> 38(7)
>  38(49)
>  (3)82401
>  98(24)01
>  98(5)7601
>  98(2)57601
>  98457(6)01
>  984(5)73601
>  9842573601

Answer (score 0):

Start with

> 987

Remove 2 digits

> 98 and 98^2= 9604

The Number becomes

> 96047

Remove again 2 digits

> 96 and 96^2=9216

The Number becomes

> 9216047

Remove one digit

> 6 and 6^2=36

The Number becomes

> 92136047

The maximum number is

> 92136047

Comment: 987 already has a 9. So is squaring 98 to get 9604 valid?

Comment: Look at the given example when you use the square of digits you replace them with the square

Comment: I wrote a computer program instead. Manual calculation of this would have been impossible.